# javascript about AOP

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

review my code make it print expected result thax

```
    var Obj = (function () {
            var b = 'b',
                    _f = function () {
                        // print arguments
                        Array.prototype.push.call(arguments,b);
                        console.log(arguments,b);
                    }

            return {
                f:_f
            };
        })();


        //rewrite Obj.f
        Obj.f = function () {
            // add parameters dynamically
            Array.prototype.push.call(arguments,333);

            // it dose not work
            Obj.f.apply(Obj.f,arguments);
        }


        //when I rewrite Obj.f how to make it print result below

        // expected result print 111 333 'b'
        Obj.f(111);
        // expected result print 666 333 'b'
        Obj.f(666);
        // expected result print 444 333 'b'
        Obj.f(444);
```

Comment: Why are you writing code like this in 2017?

Comment: add parameters dynamically for a function

Answer (score 1):

If you want the new version of `f()` to be able to call the original version of `f()` that was overwritten then you need to save a reference to the original version. Here's one way to do that:

```
    //rewrite Obj.f
    Obj.f = (function() {
      var originalF = Obj.f;
      return function () {
        // add parameters dynamically
        Array.prototype.push.call(arguments,333);

        // Call original:
        originalF.apply(this,arguments);
      }
    })();
```

That is, use an IIFE to give you some private scope for the `originalF` variable and then use that variable from within the new function. (This structure is similar to what you were already using to create your `Obj` in the first place.)

Note also that the first argument to `.apply()` sets the value of `this` within the function being called, so you probably just want to pass `this` through rather than passing `Obj.f`, so that the original function gets the same `this` as the new function. (It doesn't actually matter in your specific example, because your function doesn't use `this` at all, but still for future reference that's the most logical approach.)

Comment: thax perfect answer